# Extract Middle Substring from a given String in Unix

Tags: unix, substring

I have a string in different ranges :

```
WATSON_AJAY_AB04_DOTHING.data
WATSON_NAVNEET_CK4_DOTHING.data
WATSON_PRASHANTH_KJ56_DOTHING.data
WATSON_ABHINAV_KD323_DOTHING.data
```

On these above string how can I extract

```
AB04,CK4,KJ56,KD323
```

in Unix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "$string" | cut -d'_' -f3
```

You could use sed or grep for this task. But since the string is so simple, I dont think you will need to.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use the bash 'cut' command.  Below is an example directly on the BASH shell/command line:

```
jimm@pi$ string='WATSON_AJAY_AB04_DOTHING.data'
jimm@pi$ cut -d '_' -f 3 <<< "$string"
AB04   <-- outputs the result directly
```

*(edit: of course Lucas' answer above is also a quick 'one-liner' that does the same thing as above - he beat me to it)  :)*

The cut will take an _ character as the delimiter (the `-d '_'` part), then display the 3rd slice of the string (the `-f 3` part).

Or, if you want to output that 3rd slice from a list of content (using your list above), you can write a simple BASH script.

First, save the lines above ('WATSON...etc') into something like `text.txt`.  Then open up your favorite text editor and type:

```
#!/bin/sh
cut -d '_' -f 3 < $1
```

Save that script to some useful name like `slice.sh`, and make sure it is executable with something like `chmod 775 slice.sh`.

Then at the command line you can execute the script against your text file, and immediately get an output of those parts of the file you want (in this case the third set of text, separated by the _ character):

```
$ ./slice.sh text.txt
AB04
CK4
KJ56
KD323
```

Hope that helps!  Bear in mind that the commands above may vary a bit, depending on the flavor of *nix you are using, but it should at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: I do not think it is accurate to call 'cut' a "bash" command.  It is part of the POSIX standard utilities.   Referencing bash and then calling #!/bin/sh in your script just adds to confusion, IMO.  Maybe I am nit-picking here.

Comment: @Kajukenbo the wording at the start might need a little work, I'll grant you that.   But if you want to use cut *in a bash script*, you need #!/bin/sh so that the slice.sh script knows what environment to run in.   Unless that has changed and no-one told me? :D   (isn't resurrecting a 6-year old thread just to comment on a non-accepted answer *exactly* nit-picking.. or even slightly trolling?)  :P

Comment: That was sort of my point:  a true /bin/sh is NOT Bash.  But on most GNU/Linux systems, /bin/sh is just a symlink to /bin/bash, with some internal variable switching.  These switches still allow Bash to several things that aren't valid in /bin/sh.  Hence, adding to the confusion.  Debian derivatives are actually closer with /bin/sh being a symlink to /bin/dash.  I actually have to teach classes on this very problem.

Comment: Maybe the confusion is that you are accustomed to using #!/bin/sh when you "mean" #!/bin/bash or #!/bin/env bash ?

Comment: or just a typo in my part - I did mean #!/bin/bash  :)